# Trying to resolve a jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery

I am working with some web code that is outputted by an application I have little control over at the start it outputs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wpscripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wpscripts/jquery.wputils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wpscripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  wpRedirectMobile('http://www.--.com/m.results.php',0);
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.ActiveButton").bind({ mousedown:function(){if ( $(this).attr('disabled') === undefined ) $(this).addClass('Activated');}, mouseleave:function(){ if ( $(this).attr('disabled') === undefined ) $(this).removeClass('Activated');}, mouseup:function(){ if ( $(this).attr('disabled') === undefined ) $(this).removeClass('Activated');}});
  $("#form_2").validate({ onkeyup: false, showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) { if (errorList.length) alert(errorList[0].message); }, onclick: false, rules: { 'Property_Price': { number: true } , 'Deposit': { number: true } , 'Duration': { number: true } , 'InterestRate': { number: true }  }, onfocusout: false, messages: { 'Property_Price': { number: "Please enter the property purchase price." } , 'Deposit': { number: "Please enter your deposit amount or 0 if there is no deposit." } , 'Duration': { number: "Please enter the duration of the mortgage." } , 'InterestRate': { number: "Please enter the mortgage interest rate." }  } });
  $('#btn_4').click( function(){validate_form_2( form_2 )});
  });
</script>
```

But near the middle I have to add the following code;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>

<!-- Used to display the finger pointer image if the number of results pages exceeds 14, for mobile devices -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
if (<?php echo $totalpage?> > 14) {
    $('#fpointer').show();
}
});
</script>
```

As such the second block of code no longer works because a jquery conflict arises. If I was able to change the first block of code I could use no conflict to resolve the issue but I can't access that. If I remove the second call to jquery it works but I need that second call because on other pages the app doesn't include the first block of code so jquery isn't included.

Since no conflict only works if you add it to the first call to jquery I am stuck, is there a way to resolve this conflict by manipulating just the second block of code.

Comment: Which version of jquery is using the first block of code? same as you? (1.7)?

Comment: If there is specific rule for pages that don't include the first call to jQuery, you could create the second `<script>` tag in javascript and only include when that rule is true.

Comment: @BernieSF The first block calls 1.11 and the second 1.7

Comment: @Naz Try using same version on both code blocks

Comment: @BernieSF Tried it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can test for jQuery already existing and only load the second one if it doesn't:

```
<script>
    if(!window.jQuery) {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

I'm not a fan of using `document.write` but I think it is required to make sure the script is inserted before the rest of your code tries to run.